# From which folder should I run bii arduino:settings?

Tags: arduino, biicode

I'm new to biicode and slightly new to Arduino. I've just installed both, and I'm trying to change some biicode settings with `bii arduino:settings`, but I keep getting this message:

`ERROR: You're not in a valid project folder`

Can't find in the documentation how a valid project folder should look like, and can't see much from googling the text of my error message, so not sure what's wrong.

---

**Some extra info**:

I have installed the latest biicode version (v3.1.1) on my Mac OS, and then run

`bii setup:arduino`

By default, it installs Arduino SDK 1.0.6, but I had previously installed Arduino SDK 1.6.4, so I created a new folder in `~/.biicode_env`, and a link to my preferred Arduino installation, so this is what I have:

`~/.biicode_env/arduino-1.6.4/Arduino.app -> ~/Applications/Arduino.app`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place your code in a folder and init that folder as a biicode project running:

`bii init -L`

Then you can safely run `bii arduino:settings`. This way you can have different settings for each project.

After that, you can run:

```
bii configure -t arduino  
bii build
bii arduino:upload
```

[Note that you have to adapt your .ino files](http://blog.biicode.com/adapt-arduino-sketches-i/)

[Here's the getting started guide](http://docs.biicode.com/arduino/gettingstarted.html#create-your-project)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was not being very patient, since I've found the reply to my own question a little later in the documentation.

I just needed to create a new project like this:

`bii init myproject`

Then move inside the *myproject* directory, and run the `bii arduino:settings` command.

0:-)

Comment: Yep - both work difference is you place your code in your project folder directly with ``bii init -L`` and into blocks/username/blockname if you're using  simple ``bii init`` -> go to forum.biicode.com for further assitance ;)